# creating a simple class and its variables and function keeps returning " segmentation fault (core dumped)", C++

Tags: c++, class

I am new to c++. Ive been trying to make a class, assign private variables to it and make public funcs to modify and reach those variables later. 
Program keeps returning "Segmentation fault (core dumped) Process returned 139 (0x8B).
I know there are similar topics with this error, but not I could not find any suitable solution there. Thank you for your time.

```
# include <iostream>
# include <string>

using namespace std;

class cars{
    public:
    string yearinsert(int x) {
        year = x;
    }
    string nameinsert(string y) {
        name = y;
    }
    void nameget() {
    cout << name << endl;
    }
    void yearget() {
    cout << year << endl;
    }

private:
    int year;
private:
    string name;

};


int main(){

cars skoda;

skoda.nameinsert("Skoda");
skoda.yearinsert(2012);

skoda.nameget();
skoda.yearget();

return 0;
};
```

Comment: Turn on warnings and listen to them

Comment: I'd reccomend taking a look at [this](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) article.

Comment: How are you compiling this?

Comment: except for missing return value on the *insert function there are nothing wrong with the code. but you should pass const & for string

Comment: whoops sorry to mess with your time. didnt know there was such thing as warnings..helpful, thank you.

Comment: Aside: search for why using namespace std is bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably, the problem is solved as soon as your functions return values. This should be a compiler warning, but it is not by default.

Comment: Then, please accept the answer to let others know your issue is solved...